# How to draw a circle on a map according to its real radius in kilometers (Using UnfoldingMaps and Processing in Java)

Tags: java, maps, processing

[Earthquake threat circle on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Xjq.png)

I am using `UnfoldingMaps` to display earthquake information on the map.
I plan to show the threat circle on the map.

A circle is drawn given its radius and center position in pixels. How to get the radius is the problem I met.

Suppose I have the threat circle radius R in kilometers and the center marker A.
I want to create a marker B on the circle so that I can use the screen distance as the screen radius.

I decided to create B with the same longitude but a different latitude from A. I change R to delta latitude.

But after drawing the circle I found it is not the right one since the red triangular should be in the circle according to their distance.

The main difficulty is exactly how to calculate screen radius according to kilometers.

```
public void calcThreatCircleOnScreen(UnfoldingMap map) {
    float radius = 0;
    float deltaLat=(float) (threatCircle()/6371/2/3.1415927*360);

    Location centerLocation = this.getLocation();
    Location upperLocation = new Location(centerLocation);
    upperLocation.setLat(centerLocation.getLat() + deltaLat);

    SimplePointMarker upperMarker = new SimplePointMarker(upperLocation);
    ScreenPosition center = this.getScreenPosition(map);
    ScreenPosition upper = upperMarker.getScreenPosition(map);
    radius = Math.abs(upper.y - center.y);      
    setThreatCircleOnScreen(radius);
}
```

Comment: Start by writing code

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your effort so far. What problem did you run into? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have the answer for this question. Hope it will be helpful for others.
[Earthquake threat circle on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF9ql.png)

1. My early solution to calculate radius in pixels from km is correct. I think it a simple and powerful idea (independent of projecting API)
   The only problem is I should use diameter rather than radius in drawing the circle. I should draw with `d=2r` like this

   ```
   float d = 2 * threatCircleRadius(); 
   pg.noFill(); 
   pg.ellipse(x,y,d,d);
   ```
2. I found another cleaner solution like below by consulting the author of UnfoldingMaps. (https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/issues/124)
   My early solution first changes distance to delta latitude, then create new location by changing latitude.
   The new solution use the API GeoUtils.getDestinationLocation(sourceLocation, compassBearingDegree, distanceKm) to directly get the new location!
   In addition, I needn't create a new marker to find its screen position.

   ```
   public void calcThreatCircleOnScreen(UnfoldingMap map) {
       float radius = 0;
       Location centerLocation = this.getLocation();
       Location upperLocation = GeoUtils.getDestinationLocation(centerLocation, 0, threatCircle());

       //SimplePointMarker upperMarker = new SimplePointMarker(upperLocation);

       ScreenPosition center = map.getScreenPosition(centerLocation);
       ScreenPosition upper = map.getScreenPosition(upperLocation);
       radius = PApplet.dist(center.x, center.y, upper.x, upper.y);        
       setThreatCircleOnScreen(radius);
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on two things: the zoom level of the map, and the projection you're using.

You need to **unproject** kilometers to pixels, and you can probably figure out how to do that using google and [the Unfolding API](http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/).

For example, I found a [MercatorProjection](http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/geo/MercatorProjection.html) class that contains a constructor that takes a zoom level, and methods for projecting and unprojecting points between world coordinates and pixel coordinates.

That's just a starting point, since I'm not sure what units those methods are taking, but hopefully this is a direction for you to take your googling and experimenting.

I'd recommend trying to get something working and posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer by refereing to https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/blob/master/examples/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/examples/geo/GetDistanceApp.java